# How to dynamically change the key names of object properties in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects, like so:

```
arr = [{"timeslot":"6am7am","AVG(Monday)":10,"AVG(Tuesday)":11,"AVG(Wednesday)":7}]
```

Each object will always contain the "timeslot" property, and can contain any combination of the day-of-the-week properties, Monday through Sunday. Each day of the week may only be represented once in a single object.

I want to alter each object: specifically, the key names of the day-of-the-week properties **only** (the "timeslot" property will be unchanged"), to get an array like so:

```
newArr = [{"timeslot":"6am7am","Monday":10,"Tuesday":11,"Wednesday":7}]
```

My slightly *unreadable* solution works:

```
// Iterate the array of objects
results.forEach(function(o) {
    // Iterate the object's properties
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) {
        if(k.includes("AVG")) {
            var len = k.length;
            var pos = len - 1;
            var newKey = k.slice(4, pos); // Extract the day of the week from the key name
            o[newKey] = o[k]; // Create the new property with the same value and the new key-name
            delete o[k]; // Delete the original property
        }
    });
});
```

How can I improve this solution?

Comment: You could just write `o[k.slice(4, -1)] = o[k]`. No need for all those intermediate variables. There is not much else that could be improved.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of mutating the original array by adding and removing keys from each object, `Array#map` the array into a new array, and recreate the objects using `Array#reduce`:

```js
var arr = [{"timeslot":"6am7am","AVG(Monday)":10,"AVG(Tuesday)":11,"AVG(Wednesday)":7}];

var result = arr.map(function(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(r, key) {    
    var k = key.includes('AVG') ? key.slice(4, -1) : key;
    
    r[k] = obj[key];
    
    return r;
  }, {});
});

console.log(result);
```